# ASP.NET MVC Get File Upload name with user id and apply to separate field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, filenames, userid

I have file download and upload working properly but I am trying to add user id to the beginning of the file name as well as apply the file name to a separate field.

For Example:

Upload File : (UserID)_FileName.docx

FileName: (UserID)_FileName.docx

The reason I want it like this is because I am uploading the file to the server instead of the DB but I want the DB to have record of the file name for the specific user who uploaded the file.

In my controller Create() I have this snippet for the upload

```
if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = User.Identity.GetUserId() + "_" + Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadFiles"), fileName);
                    file.SaveAs(path);
                }
```

In the cshtml I have the following two fields

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Upload File", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="file" name="file" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FileName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBox("FileName", (object)ViewBag.FileName)
            </div>
        </div>
```

For the ViewBag.FileName in the controller I have:

```
ViewBag.Resume = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
```

In the end I actually will have the FileName field hidden or just handled during POST. So I am sure there is a different/better way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured it out on my own after a few hours. SMH I was over complicating it.

In the Controller I added

```
      var userName = User.Identity.GetUserName();
      var userAccount = db.users.Where(m => m.Email == userName).ToList();
      var userId = userAccount[0].UserID; 

      var fileName = userId + "_" + Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
      application.FileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
```

and I removed the FileName field from the cshtml and the "ViewBag.FileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);" from the controller.

Removed from cshtml

```
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.FileName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
      <div class="col-md-10">
             @Html.TextBox("FileName", (object)ViewBag.FileName)
      </div>
</div>
```